# How to access state of the contract per transaction event?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3.py

I've a contract which has a price attribute. Price goes up with each transaction.

```
contract MyContract{
    uint256 public price;

    .... other methods
}
```

For transaction I receive following event data in a callback:

```
{ address: '0xa6....................',
  blockNumber: 15655,
  transactionHash: '0xb..........................',
  transactionIndex: 1,
  blockHash: '0xca........................',
  logIndex: 0,
  removed: false,
  event: 'Transfer',
  args:
   { from: '0x3dc..................',
     to: '0x64b...................',
     amount: 1 
    }
```

}

Is there a way I could obtain the price of the contract, at a specific transaction using above event data(which has already happened)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the location of the price in storage (e.g. 0, if it's the first state variable), then you can use [`web3.eth.getStorageAt`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetstorageat):

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 0, blockNumber);
```

**EDIT**

Per @carver's comment below, this doesn't really give you a per-transaction view, just a per-block view.

Comment: Could you please explain what is storage location? Is it the position of the attribute in the contract? If I had another single attribute before "price", "price" location will be 1?

Comment: It depends how big the thing before `price` is. If it's 256 bits, then yes. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage for the details.

Comment: I see. But I still don't understand how I could relate transactionHash to it? Kindly check the update to the question, I added the event data I receive in the callback.

Comment: The transaction hash gives you the block number. You pass the block number as the third parameter to `web3.eth.getStorageAt`.

Comment: thank you very much, for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple transactions in a block, you will only see the price state at the end of the last transaction this way. The best answer is to change the event (or add a new one) to include the price.

Comment: @carver Great point. Edited.

Comment: @carver yes, I added another event  PriceChanged(previousPrice, newPrice), since Transfer event is part of ERC20 specification. Now I've to find out if this additional event going to require more gas (:

Comment: @sanandrl emitting a new log will definitely require more gas, the question is how much. If you indexed both fields, then it should be in the vicinity of 1200 more gas. No indices would be closer to 400.